# Revealing module pattern: object is undefined

Tags: javascript, revealing-module-pattern

I am trying to implement the revealing module pattern in my js files in IE8. Given this code:

```
var foo = (function () {
//private members
var a, b, c, d;
var init = function () {
    var self = this;
    //public members
    var A, B, C, D
    var privateFunc = function () {
        /*..*/
    };
    var publicFunc = function () {
        /*..*/
    };
    return {
        A: A,
        B: B,
        C: C,
        D: D,
        publicFunc: publicFunc
    }
  }
} ());
$(function () {
  foo.init();
})
```

My issue is that in the jQuery document ready function, foo is always undefined, and I can't figure out what the problem is.

Comment: Your JavaScript is invalid. Where does the `init()` function end?

Comment: Please link us to your actual code. Perhaps a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ "Create a new Fiddle - jsFiddle").

Comment: And, if you're having trouble with indenting, visit http://jsbeautifier.org/

Answer (score 0):

The issue was that I was returning the public objects from the init function instead of from foo. Thanks for your help, all.